Why is Ammonia a strong base?
I'm new to my chemistry journey and am wondering why $\ce{NH3}$ is a strong base. I thought bases were supposed to donate electron groups, but I haven't found any example where $\ce{NH3}$ does that. I understand that it can take on a proton to become ammonium ($\ce{NH4^+}$), which is another definition of a base, but taking on a proton is not donating an electron group. This might be a simple question to answer, (and I probably seem stupid), but I can't find anything online about it.

It donates both electrons to the bond with H+, what is the donation of the electron pair (not group). That qualifies as being bot Broensted-Lawry and Lewis base.// But, ammonia is NOT a string base, like NaOH is.

Ammonia is not considered a strong base. Its pkb is around 4.75, compared to 0.2 for NaOH

Ammonia (NH₃) is a weak base, not a strong base. Here's the simple reason:
Ammonia has a lone pair of electrons on nitrogen, which lets it grab a proton (H⁺) from water. This makes hydroxide ions (OH⁻) in the process:
NH3+H2O→NH 4++OH−
However, ammonia does not grab all the protons in water. Only a small amount reacts, so it doesn't make as much OH⁻ as a strong base like NaOH does.

NaOH doesn't "make" any HO- since the net reaction is $\ce{HO- + H2O <=> H2O + HO-}$

NaOH[s] + H2O  = Na+ +Cl- both hydrated in solution. Addition of NaOH to water Increases the hydroxide concentration. Strong and weak acid and base terms are relative not definitive and usually apply to aqueous solutions. The basicity and acidity are compared to those of water, H3O+, and OH-. All 3 explanations of acidity are continually involved.  Ammonia can be a strong base or more appropriately a nucleophile in anhydrous media
